# Im making a program that makes random math, but it does not work

Tags: javascript, html

So this is the program:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
  <button onclick="Kaas()">Controleer</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo2"></p>
  <p id="demo3"></p>
  <p id="demo4"></p>

  <script>
  var z= 0;
  function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
    var z = x-y
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = z;
  }

  var a=0;
  function Kaas() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    
    if(x==z){
      document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Correct";
    }else{
      if(a==3){
        document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Fout, het goede   antwoord is" + z;
      }else{
        document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Fout, probeer het nog een keer";
        a +=1;   
      }
    }
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it isn't working. I was trying to make it so I type in the correct answer and then it would say correct or incorrect.

Also I wanted it to say the correct answer after 3 times.

Comment: What is it supposed to do? How does it "not work"? Are there any errors?

Comment: You're redeclaring z inside `myFunction`.  The global z is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redefining `z` variable as local. Outer was never changed.
Just remove `var` before `z` inside your function:

```js
var z= 0;
function myFunction() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  z = x - y;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = z;
}

var a=0;
function Kaas() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
  if (x==z) {
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Correct";
  } else {
    if (a==3) {
      document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Fout, het goede antwoord is" + z;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Fout, probeer het nog een keer";
      a += 1;   
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<input type="number" id="myNumber" value="">
<button onclick="Kaas()">Controleer</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<p id="demo3"></p>
<p id="demo4"></p>
```